# SQL, Update with most recent data info

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 2 tables shown below:

```
Table 1
Student ID - DATE_NO - SCORE
```

```
Table 2
STUDENT_ID - DATE_NO - HT - WT
```

Table 1 has the physical test scores and the date of the test for each student while Table 2 lists their height (HT) and weight (WT) and the date they were measured.

Example Data:

```
Table 1
Student ID | DATE_NO | SCORE |
125        |    3    |   90  |
572        |    6    |   75  |
687        |    11   |   95  |
```

```
Table 2
Student_ID | DATE_NO | HT |  WT  |
125        |   2     | 70 | 150  |
125        |   3     | 72 | 155  |
125        |   6     | 72 | 160  |
572        |   2     | 70 | 200  |
572        |   5     | 70 | 225  |
572        |   8     | 70 | 215  |
572        |   9     | 70 | 220  |
687        |   4     | 65 | 140  |
687        |   7     | 67 | 150  |
687        |   11    | 70 | 155  |
687        |   12    | 67 | 160  |
```

I am not guaranteed to have the exact same DATE_NO for both HT/WT and the Test score date. I want the most recent HT and WT for each student when they took their physical test. Based on the example data above, the optimal join would give me the table below:

```
Modified Table 1
Student ID | DATE_NO | HT |  WT  |
125        |    3    | 72 |  155 |
572        |    6    | 70 |  225 |
687        |    11   | 70 |  155 |
```

I'd like to use the UPDATE statement on Table 1, so after altering Table 1 with HT int and WT int, I attempt to do the following:

```
UPDATE T1
SET HT = T2.HT, WT = T2.WT
FROM Table_1 as T1
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS T2 ON T1.STUDENT_ID = T2.STUDENT_ID
WHERE (T1.DATE_NO) >= (T2.DATE_NO)
```

But the result gives me the FIRST record that meets the criteria. Switching greater than to less than [ >= to <=  ] Make the HT/WT for each student the entries for Month 6,8, and 12) when it should be month 3,8, and 11. Any suggestions?

FYI: Won't be able to apply any solutions till Friday.

Comment: Which dbms??????  The syntax is different from one dbms to another.  SQL is just a language.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. My bad.

Comment: You asked an unclear question.

Comment: Update replaces data.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes. I need the data all in one table with their corresponding STUDENT_ID and DATES. I'll be doing more aggregating later.

Comment: This question is poorly asked. You start out with Table 1 and Table 2, then out of nowhere we have TEST_SCORES and HT_WT. It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something like this you're looking for:

```
UPDATE Q
SET
    T1_HT = T2_HT
    , T1_WT = T2_WT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T1.HT T1_HT
            , T1.WT T1_WT
            , T2.HT T2_HT
            , T2.WT T2_WT
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.STUDENT_ID ORDER BY T2.DATE_NO DESC) R
        FROM
            Table_1 T1
            JOIN Table_2 T2 ON
                T1.STUDENT_ID = T2.STUDENT_ID
                AND T2.DATE_NO <= T1.DATE_NO
    ) Q
WHERE R = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This nearly solves what I was seeking to do. The 'updating' table is TEST_SCORES, so adding in TEST_SCORES.STUDENT_ID = Q.STUDENT_ID affixed the correct HT and WT to each record. Otherwise the update recorded the same WT to all records for some reason. =p  Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ts.student_id,
       ts.date_no,
       hw.ht,
       hw.wt
FROM test_scores ts,
     ht_wt hw
WHERE hw.student_id = ts.student_id
  AND hw.date_no <= ts.date_no
  AND hw.date_no =
    (SELECT max(date_no)
     FROM ht_wt
     WHERE date_no <= ts.date_no
       AND student_id = ts.student_id)
```

sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/684f6/4)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does pull up the needed info but I needed it with an update statement. Good to know I can do this as well if the situation arises. Thanks!